# PHP to remove all table tr td tags

Tags: php, regex, string, tags

I am looking for a way to remove all `<table*> <tr*> <td*> </td> </tr> </table>` tags from a string.
Where the * is a wildcard for anything else.

What are the regexs for this, so I can use str_replace?

Comment: Just the tags? What about what's inside of the tags?

Comment: Yes, what is inside the tags too, that is what I meant with the *

Comment: I think you misunderstood, i think @Truth meant the content, and you mean the attributes

Comment: Oh yes sorry, just the tags, please leave the content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `strip_tags()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

As long as there are not too many tags that need to be allowed through the filter, it is the easiest way.

Answer (score 6):

Probably regex is not the best solution but try this:

```
echo preg_replace('/\<[\/]?(table|tr|td)([^\>]*)\>/i', '', $text);
```

Comment: with little modyfication ;-)  echo preg_replace('/\<[\/]?(table|tbody|tr|td)([^\>]*)\>/i', '', $text);

Answer (score -3):

don't use regex on html .. won't work .. use something like [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)